# PHP - Validating a registration form

Tags: php, forms, validation, registration

How do I validate the first name to only contain a-z characters using php. I have the following at the moment:

```
 if (empty($myFirstName)) {
    echo "<p>Please enter your first name!</p>";
else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]$/", $myFirstName)){
    echo "Your first name can only contain letters!";
}
```

Comment: As you can do it with php, I found it to be a best practice using client side validations using javascript for example

Comment: Client side validation involves a security risk as it is a registration form, you must ALWAYS do a server side check.

Comment: Your validation script looks good but its having syntax error. should be `if (empty($myFirstName)) 
    echo "<p>Please enter your first name!</p>";
else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]$/", $myFirstName))
    echo "Your first name can only contain letters!";
`

Comment: There is just a } bracket missing right before else, by the way, may I wonder why the first message contains <p> tags and the second doesn't?

Comment: @Rsauxil Could you explain why please?

Comment: If you do client side validation without server side validation, the user can turn his javascript off, resulting in NO validation. If you want to limit the users from using any username/first name/whatever, client side validation would not suffice.

Comment: Also, have you thought of the fact that people can have a first name like Anne-Marie or a last name like O'Neil?

Comment: I thought that for trivial validation (like this one) is enough to do a client side validation, once this one return ok, then you can do the server side one if you need it

Comment: whats the main difference between server and client side validation? as in validation in the form input vs php validation? which one wuld be better?

ah I've added the <p> to the second line now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working code :

```
if (empty($myFirstName)) {
    echo "<p>Please enter your first name!</p>";}

else if(preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z]/", $myFirstName)){
    echo "Your first name can only contain letters!";
}
```

I did a little modification to the regex : I added a `^` in the group, and removed the anchors.

As a result, your regex will match any character which is not a letter, and display the error message if there is a match.

I strongly advice you to validate user input at least on server side, and on client side if you want to.

For an email validation, the html filter works on client side.

On server side, you can use pre-set PHP filters :

```
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo "email OK";
}
```

FYI, there is a regexp matching emails according to the RFC2822 standards :

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

Comment: Yaii it works now! I see where i  whent wrong.. forgot the closing } in the first If statment.. 

Thank you Theox for your advice, i've used it now :) 


are there any good e-mail validaions that can be used? At the moment because i have `<input name="email" type="email">` it kind of does it for me. Is that good or bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use

```
if(! ctype_alpha($myFirstName) )
{
  //check for alphabetic inputs only
  echo "Your first name can only contain letters!";
}
```

<kbd>[Php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` is incorrect.

```
!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]$/", $myFirstName)
```

will only hold true if `$myFirstName` is `not a single alpha character`

to ensure that `$myFirstName` is `not any number of alpha characters`, try

```
!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $myFirstName)
```